Trying to connect Python program with OpenAI API Key. Error
I have used Google, ChatGPT and all other possible resources to solve the problem of connection error. I am using PyCharm to run a Python code that is as follows.
.env:
OPENAI_API_KEY = "Actual Value"
 

0_start.py:
from SimplerLLM.language.llm import LLM, LLMProvider

llm_instance = LLM.create(provider=LLMProvider.OPENAI, model_name="text-davinci-003")

generated_text = llm_instance.generate_response(prompt="generate a sentence of 5 words")

print(generated_text)

Error:
Failed after 3 attempts due to: Connection error.
None

Could it be because of the company laptop is blocking the connection with Firewall etc.?
